# Is it possible to perform a batch action on all of the records after filtering in activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I need to perform a batch action on all of the records after filtering in activeadmin. I've read following question: [ActiveAdmin: batch select all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159477/activeadmin-batch-select-all-pages) but in this case select is fairly simple. We can use just `Model.all` or something similar. But is it possible to select all of the records on all of the pages after the filter was applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post my solution to this in order to help someone else with similar issues.

So I thought about `link_to :back` and understood that rails should have some object that holds previous URL, and some method for retrieving this data. In rails, ActiveDispatch is responsible for handling requests and related things. Inside controllers we can use `request` object (which is instance of ActiveDispatch::Request) to access this data. What we need is `request.referer` method.

After we find URL we need to parse its params, perform search and later on we can handle this data as we need to. In my case submit ids of users that was found to the template, collect specific user input and submit our input with user ids to update them all.

By the way, there is a handy method to parse URL:

```
Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query
```