# Active Admin select all rows from all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

We are using Active Admin at our work place. 
One of the feature request is, to be able to select all rows across all pages and perform a `batch action` on them, after applying `filters`.

So far it only selects the row in the current page.

I've been looking around for a while haven't found and working solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159477/activeadmin-batch-select-all-pages

Comment: @Vishal this won't work with filters right?

Comment: I suggest the subject should be more like "ActiveAdmin select filtered rows for batch action from all pages" so more users will find this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [active_admin_scoped_collection_actions](https://github.com/activeadmin-plugins/active_admin_scoped_collection_actions), it should be just what you want.